# Cannot loop through yaml.MapItem.Value in go

Tags: go, yaml

I'm trying to parse a yaml file while keeping the order (due to foreign key issues) of tables being processed.

**fixtures.yaml**

```
table1:
  -id: 1
   field1: "some value"
   field2: "some value"

table2:
  -id: 1
   field1: "some value"
   field2: "some value"

...some more data...
```

**main.go**

```
yamlContent, err := ioutil.ReadFile("fixtures.yaml")
yamlOutput := yaml.MapSlice{}

err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlContent, &yamlOutput)
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, tableData := range yamlOutput {
  //Table Name
  fmt.Println(tableData.Key)

  //Table Data
  fmt.Println(tableData.Value)

  // Error here
  for _, row := range tableData.Value {
    fmt.Println(row)
  }
}
```

The value of **tableData.Value** looks something like this:

```
[[{id 1} {field1 some value} {field2 some value} {field3 some value} {field4 some value} {field5 some value}]]
```

The problem is I cannot range through `tableData.Value`. Whenever I do, I get the error:

```
cannot range over tableData.Value (type interface {})
```

But whenever I use `reflect.TypeOf(tableData.Value)`, I get `[]interface {}`

What should I do to be able to loop through each row and then through each key value pair? I'm pretty new in Go so I'm not really sure what to do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a value that has *static* type `interface{}` whose *dynamic* type is `[]interface{}` then you have to [type-assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) it to the dynamic type to be able to range over the slice.

```golang
if v, ok := tableData.Value.([]interface{}); ok {
    for _, row := range v {
        fmt.Println(row)
    }
}
```

---

https://play.golang.org/p/D16JKPglcaW